# Trouble with JavaScript in Google sheets, stripping punctuation

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I want to take a selection from google sheets and create a csv file while stripping out certain punctuation. I've found the solution to both on stack overflow but I"m having problems when i try combining the two. The code still runs but it does not strip any punctuation. Here is the code. only showing the relevant function.

```
function convertRangeToCsvFile_(csvFileName) {
  // Get the selected range in the spreadsheet
  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSelection();
  try {
    var data = ws.getValues();
    var csvFile = undefined;

    // Loop through the data in the range and build a string with the CSV data
    if (data.length > 1) {
      var csv = "";
      for (var row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
        for (var col = 0; col < data[row].length; col++) {
          var stringy = data[row][col].toString()
          stringy.replace(/,/g , "newchar");
          if (stringy.indexOf(",") != -1) {
            data[row][col] = "\"" + stringy + "\"";

          }
        }

        // Join each row's columns
        // Add a carriage return to end of each row, except for the last one
        if (row < data.length-1) {
          csv += data[row].join(",") + "\r\n";
        }
        else {
          csv += data[row];
        }
      }
      csvFile = csv;
    }
    return csvFile;
  }
```

What i thought I was doing here was taking the current cell in the loop, putting it in my new variable stringy and stripping the punctuation. Then putting stringy back in the list. But this is not happening because "newchar" doesn't show up where the commas are. Any help is appreciated

Comment: **Java (not to be confused with JavaScript or JScript)**

Comment: Java is to JavaScript, as a Car is to a Carpet or a Ham is to a Hamster. This is JavaScript.

Comment: Sorry. Novice programmer. Should have been more careful how I titled this question.

Answer (score 0):

Being the novice that I am I forgot strings are immutable. I needed to create a new string variable to put into the list.

Change from this:

```
stringy.replace(/,/g , "newchar");
data[row][col] = "\"" + stringy + "\"";
```

to this:

```
var newstring = stringy.replace(/,/g , "");
data[row][col] = "\"" + newstring + "\"";
```

now i get the results I want.